# Handiling Undo in Content Editable Div

Tags: html, undo

I was trying to design a editor using content Editable DIV.I want to handle the undo option (ctrl+z).I am able to listen to event.But i found that IE handles this key and undoes only the
content we typed in and not any html content that is dynamically inserted(like a table).So i wrote this piece of code to check if i can prevent browser from handiling the ctrl+z event.

```
function keydownevent(e)
{
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode==90)
 {
   alert('aa').
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
 }
```

}

the output is the browser is clearing the content and then giving alert message.How to prevent this from happening?